# Phonegap Hide Backend URL link code

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-build

I have been creating Phonegap apps.  I searched the web as well as here to find that there is no way you can hide your code for Phonegap apps.

I do use obfuscation and that serves the purpose of protecting the code somewhat.

Is there a way to hide the back-end API URL links that I am using?
The links to the server are still available even after obfuscation.

Is there a way to do this? or a work around?

Comment: eh, I'd focus on making sure your endpoints are properly filtering out malicious crap instead of trying to hide the endpoint. There are just too many ways to inspect http traffic. Put ssl over it and encode/filter all user input.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this algorithm, and adjusted it for my own purpose, but lets take this one as an example:

http://www.mvjantzen.com/blog/?p=1005

U have your key

```
var key = function () {
    return 'SXGWLZPDOKFIVUHJYTQBNMACERxswgzldpkoifuvjhtybqmncare';
};

Decrypt
var _decodeStr = function(coded) {
    coded = decodeURIComponent(coded);
    var uncoded = '';
    var chr;
    for (var i = coded.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        chr = coded.charAt(i);
        uncoded += (chr >= 'a' && chr <= 'z' || chr >= 'A' && chr <= 'Z') ?
            String.fromCharCode(65 + key().indexOf(chr) % 26) :
            chr;
    }
    return uncoded.toLowerCase();
};

Encrypt
var _encodeStr = function(uncoded) {
    uncoded = uncoded.toUpperCase().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
    var coded = '';
    var chr;
    for (var i = uncoded.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        chr = uncoded.charCodeAt(i);
        coded += (chr >= 65 && chr <= 90) ?
            key.charAt(chr - 65 + 26*Math.floor(Math.random()*2)) :
            String.fromCharCode(chr);
    }
    return encodeURIComponent(coded);
}


var encodedUrl = _encodeStr('http://www.whateverul.com/api/call/');
_decodeStr(encodedUrl); // fake encrypted url
```

so the url that u got encode, u can use wherever u wanna use it, just call it with the decoder,

Remove the encoder from your source files.

This give u somewhat of a way for people when they are searching tru your code for generic lines like http:/// or api.bla.com/call or whatever, its harder to find.

But u cannot totally hide it, this just makes it a little bit harder, i use this method in my phonegap apps, i also don't use clear function names, don't name your function encryptedUrlDecoder() or something:P
and even if u do, they can always sniff the outgoing calls etc, but this helps a bit (atleast when somebody is reverse engeneering your code)

after encrypting obfuscate/minimize your js code, to make it even more complex to read

i hope this helps u a bit :) good luck!